# Show a sequence is Cauchy iff $\lim_{N\to\infty} \operatorname{diam} E_N = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

So this is right out of Rudin, but doesn't offer a proof or anything, just simply says that "given the definition of a Cauchy sequence and the definition of a diameter, the proof is clear."  The sequence in question is $E_N = {p_N, p_{N+1}..}$.  But I just don't quite understand. From the text, the diameter is the supremum of the distance of the points in the set.  How does the supremum of $E_N$ approach $0$ for large $N$?

Comment: The diameter of a set is not the supremum of the set.  It's the supremum of the *distance between* points in the set.

Comment: Whoops, I was sloppy.  Supremum of the distance between the points because the points that form the diameter don't necessarily need to be included in the set, yes?

Comment: right. But that "distance between points" should connect with the definition of Cauchy sequence.

Comment: I have a question, what if $diamE_1$ doesn't exist, then?

Comment: Or is it saying that the sequence starts from $N$, where this $N$ works for Cauchy sequence $(p_n)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given $\epsilon > 0$, we want to find $N$ so that for all indices $m,n \geq N$, $d(p_m,p_n) < \epsilon$. By definition,
$$ \operatorname{diam} E_N \equiv \sup\{d(p,q)\mid p,q \in E\} = \sup\{d(p_m,p_n)\mid m,n \geq N \}
$$
We can choose $N$ so that $\operatorname{diam} E_N < \epsilon$. Since $\sup\{d(p_m,p_n)\mid m,n \geq N \}$ is the upper bound of $d(p_m,p_n)$, $(p_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ is Cauchy.

The converse is similar.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time.  I can start the converse but can't quite complete it, i'm unsure how to show the limit of the diameter of $E_N$ = 0.  Is my attempt below correct?

Suppose ${x_n}$ is Cauchy.  Then, for some given $\epsilon$, we have $|p_n - p_m| < \epsilon$ for $n, m \geq N$.  From $$diam E_N = \sup  {d(p_m, p_n) | m,n \geq N}$$ we have the upperbound of the distances of $p_m, p_n$.  But this is just $|diam E_N - 0| < \epsilon$ for all $n, m \geq N$.

Is this correct?

Comment: @badeconomist By the same logic you can choose $N$ so that $d(p_m,p_n) < \epsilon/2$ for $n,m \geq n$. Then $\epsilon/2$ is guarenteed to be an upper bound of $d(p_m,p_n)$. Since $\sup d(p_m,p_n)$ is the least upper bound, $\sup d(p_m,p_n) \leq \epsilon/2 < \epsilon$. Hence for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ with $\operatorname{diam} E_N < \epsilon$, which is the precise definition of limit.

Comment: @HenricusV. No. The definition of limit is $d(diam E_N,0) < \epsilon$, so this does not seem valid.

Comment: @Math_QED Diameter cannot be negative so they are equivalent.

Comment: So you are saying that $d(diam E_n,0) = diam E_N$ whatever the metric $d$ is supposed to be? I can't see why.

Comment: @Math_QED $d$ is the Euclidean metric.

Comment: Yes, I see it is true then, but Rudin does not mention this in his book. Did he forget to state that?

Answer (score 1):

$E_N \supset E_{N+1}$ is obvious.
So, $\operatorname{diam} E_N \geq \operatorname{diam} E_{N+1}$ is obvious.

Let $\{p_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence.
Let $\epsilon$ be an arbitrary positive real number.

There is $N \in \{1, 2, \cdots\}$ such that if $n, m \geq N$, then $d(p_n, p_m) < \epsilon$.
So, $\operatorname{diam} E_N \leq \epsilon$.
Because $\operatorname{diam} E_N \geq \operatorname{diam} E_{N+1}$, $\lim_{N \to \infty} \operatorname{diam} E_N = 0$.

Conversely,
Let $\lim_{N \to \infty} \operatorname{diam} E_N = 0$.
Let $\epsilon$ be an arbitrary positive real number.

Because $\lim_{N \to \infty} \operatorname{diam} E_N = 0$, there exists $N \in \{1, 2, \cdots\}$ such that $\operatorname{diam} E_N < \epsilon$.
So, if $n, m \geq N$, then $d(x_n, x_m) \leq \operatorname{diam} E_N < \epsilon$.